# libssl / openssl error though package is installed

Tags: linux

Im having the following problem.

Both of my Virtualmachines are showing the same error though libssl-dev and openssl-dev is installed.
Is there another fix for this or do I need to try setting it up again?

gcc: error: /opt/local/include/openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /opt/local/include/openssl/e_os2.h: No such file or directory
gcc: error: /opt/local/include/openssl/opensslconf.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [obj/scrypt.o] Error 1

Comment: Your build environment seems to be looking for `openssl` in `/opt/local`, but it is unlikely that the system packages are installed in that location. You probably need to update your Makefile or other tooling to point to the correct directories.

Comment: Im unable to copy there and would like to know how I can link the directory in my makefile. Many thanks!

Comment: In my make life the LIBS are stated as this: 
How do I link the right location? LIBS = $(addprefix -L,$(BOOST_LIB_PATH) $(BDB_LIB_PATH) $(OPENSSL_LIB_PATH))

Answer (score 0):

```
traaitt@ubuntu:~$ cd /opt/
traaitt@ubuntu:/opt$ cd local
traaitt@ubuntu:/opt/local$ sudo mkdir include
traaitt@ubuntu:/opt/local$ cd include
traaitt@ubuntu:/opt/local/include$ sudo mkdir openssl
traaitt@ubuntu:/opt/local/include$ cd openssl
traaitt@ubuntu:/opt/local/include/openssl$ 

sudo ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink
sudo ln -s /usr/include/openssl/sha.h /opt/local/include/openssl/sha.h
sudo ln -s /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h /opt/local/include/openssl/e_os2.h
sudo ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl /opt/local/include/openssl/opensslconf.h
```

Comment: now getting this error: because of the symlinks I guess
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.